# Akka Gotchas when dealing with Futures

Tags: akka, future

Consider the following code bit:

```
def receive = {
  case ComputeResult(itemId: Long) =>
    //val originalSender = sender
    computeResult(itemId).map { result =>
      originalSender ! result
    }
}
```

The computeResult results in a Future, so how would the introduction of a val prevent my from sending the result to the wrong sender? Let us say I have a completely different Senders (sender1 and sender2).

Sender1 first sends a message followed by Sender2. Without the val in my method above, I clearly see that there is a possibility that my Sender2 could get the result that was actually meant for Sender1.

What I don't get is that how would the introduction of a val prevent me from the scenario that I just described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sender` is actually a function (that's why the convention from Akka 2.3 onwards is to write `sender()`).  By binding the value to `originalSender`, we can close over that immutable value and know that it won't change, even if another message comes in before the Future from `completeResult` completes.

Because `receive` is a function, every invocation will result in a new local value called `originalSender`.